# How can I use my GeoJSON data in my next.js app with leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, next.js, geojson, react-leaflet

In my Next.js app I try to use multiple locations on my leaflet map by using a GeoJSON data file.
When I use one location in the map it works just fine, but when I import the data and map over it to show more points on the map, I run in two the Unhandled Runtime Errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null
and
TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined

When I console log the imported data I can see the correct data.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?
This are the files I use:

*components/Map/index.js*

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const Map = dynamic(
  () => import('./Map'),
  { ssr: false }
)

export default Map;
```

*components/Map/Map.js*

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import * as data from './seedlibraryData.json';

function Map() {
  // console.log('data geometry coordinate 1', data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0])
  // console.log('data geometry coordinate 2', data.features[0].geometry.coordinates[1])
  return(
    <div>
      <MapContainer 
        center={[52.080190, 4.310130]} 
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
        className="leaflet-container"
        >
         <TileLayer
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />
          {data.features.map(seedlibrary => (
             <Marker
              key={seedlibrary.properties.library_ID}
              position={
                seedlibrary.geometry.coordinates[1],
                seedlibrary.geometry.coordinates[0]
                }
              animate={false}
            /> 
          ))}
          
            <Popup>
              Text
            </Popup>
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Map
```

*components/Map/seedlibraryData.json:*

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "library_ID": "01",
        "location_name": "Stadsoase Spinozahof",
        "street": "Repelaerstraat 61",
        "zipcode": "2515 LX",
        "city": "Den Haag",
        "website": "http://stadsoasespinozahof.nl/"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [52.072421, 4.315050]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "library_ID": "02",
        "location_name": "Hof van Wouw",
        "street": "Lange Beestenmarkt 49-85",
        "zipcode": "2512 EB",
        "city": "Den Haag",
        "website": "https://hofvanwouw.nl/"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [52.073980, 4.307760]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

*pages/index.js:*

```
import React from 'react';
import Map from '../components/Map/'

function HomePage() {

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Map />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

EDIT:
I found the solution: @ghybs pointed me in the good direction. I checked again the leaflet-react documentation. The popup tag should be inside the Marker tag. Instead I placed a self closing Marker tag in it.

*Map.js solution:*

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';
import * as data from './seedlibraryData.json';

function Map() {
  return(
    <div>
      <MapContainer 
        center={[52.080190, 4.310130]} 
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
        className="leaflet-container"
        >
         <TileLayer
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          />
          {data.features.map(seedlibrary => (
             <Marker
              key={seedlibrary.properties.library_ID}
              position={[
                seedlibrary.geometry.coordinates[0],
                seedlibrary.geometry.coordinates[1]
              ]}
              animate={false}
              >
              <Popup>
                {seedlibrary.properties.location_name}
                {seedlibrary.properties.street}
                {seedlibrary.properties.zipcode}{seedlibrary.properties.city}
              </Popup>
            </Marker>
          ))}
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Map
```

Comment: There is no where in the files you have attached a place where you are accessing `.lat`. It should be somewhere else in your code

Comment: Does it work when you replace the variables with static values? `seedlibrary.geometry.coordinates[1]` with `4.307760` ...

Comment: Your popup misses some attributes (like position)

Comment: Have you validated your GeoJSON data, e.g. using a lint tool like https://geojsonlint.com/

Comment: I found it! thanks to @ghybs . I checked the syntax again if I was wrong. The Popup should be within the Marker tags e.g. <Marker><Popup></Popup><Marker>. My Marker was self closing tag

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax to specify Marker position is suspicious:

```
<Marker
  position={
                seedlibrary.geometry.coordinates[1],
                seedlibrary.geometry.coordinates[0]
                }
/>
```

Seems like you should write the coordinates as an array, e.g.:

```
<Marker
  position={[
                seedlibrary.geometry.coordinates[1],
                seedlibrary.geometry.coordinates[0]
                ]}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion about the popup. I pointed me to the right direction.